# rails 4 cross model named scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

What I want to do is create appropriate named scopes to get all reports of a logged in user that were created 3 days ago

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appraisals

end

class Appraisal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :report

    scope :submitted, -> { joins(:report).where("reports.created_at >= ?", 3.days.ago) }
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :appraisal
end
```

I've tried different rails console statements but perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way.

In the rails console I've tried various things but I keep getting this error

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "report"

with statements such as

```
user = User.find(2)
user.appraisals.submitted
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `joins(:report).where("reports.created_at >= ?", 3.days.ago)`. What is your table name in the database?

Comment: apologies, I made a boo boo.  I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `joins` you have to specify the association name like this:

```
scope :submitted, -> { joins(:report).where("appraisal_reports.created_at >= ?", 3.days.ago) }
```

Comment: `appraisal_reports` probably needs to be changed in the `where` as well.

Comment: Possibly. Depends on the table name.